# Shared Element Transition between fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-transitions

I am working with animating transitions between `fragment` and `activity`. The problem I am experiencing is when I do the call for transition from my fragment to new Activity, the `SharedElement` which is an `ImageView`, gets really small and then grows bigger. When the activity is closed and the element gets back to its position, it shrinks all the way to zero and then pops to the normal size.

The very similar problem is shown in this video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzli11ae3ebz95f/2016_04_19_20_33_29.mp4?dl=0

Here is the code for my new activity:

```
final ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity,
                    Pair.create((View) holder.sharedElement, "transition_name1"),
                    Pair.create((View) holder.sharedElement2, "transition_name2"));


            final Intent intent = SecondActivity.startActivity(mActivity, mList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, SecondActivity.REQUEST_CODE, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

And after I get to the new activity, I am making this Transitions:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setupTransitions() {
    TransitionSet sharedSetEnter = new TransitionSet();

    Transition bounds = new ChangeBounds();
    bounds.addTarget("transition_name2");
    bounds.excludeTarget(R.id.toolbar, true);
    bounds.setDuration(300);

    Transition arcShared = new ChangeBounds();
    arcShared.addTarget("transition_name1");
    arcShared.setPathMotion(new ArcMotion());
    arcShared.setDuration(200);

    sharedSetEnter.addTransition(arcShared);
    sharedSetEnter.addTransition(bounds);

    TransitionSet sharedSetExit = new TransitionSet();
    sharedSetExit.addTransition(arcShared);
    sharedSetExit.addTransition(bounds);

    Transition fade = new Fade();
    fade.setDuration(100);
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

    sharedSetEnter.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
            initLayouts();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {}
        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {}
        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {}
        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {}
    });

    sharedSetExit.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
            setUnnecessaryLayoutsInvisible();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {}
        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {}
        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {}
    });

    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(sharedSetEnter);
    getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(sharedSetExit);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
    getWindow().setReturnTransition(fade);

}
```

So the animations are called ok with the exception of the ImageView, which does not scale as it should. The size goes from 0-1 and from 1-0 instead of like 0.4-1 and 1-0.4

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please let me know how to do perform shared element Transition from fragment to activity in android ?

Comment: The first part of code is good enough for fragment to activity transition